# How to create navigation node restriction for usergroup in Hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, restriction

I have restriction CMSUserGroupRestriction where I give my usergroup a restriction to see my navigation node link. In backoffice I have correct info about this restriction, but in storefront I still can see it. I think that's because of my navigation node got attached image to it, so i need to add restriction not just for link of nav node, but on all of it. Adding in to CMSUserGroupRestriction not working. Can you describe how to give restriction for usergroup on navigation node at all?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the exact requirement but see if this help

Check **Front End Visibility Controls**

**Category Visibility**

Each category has an attribute that specifies the users or user groups who are allowed to see and browse the category. 
You can find this underCategory Visibility on the General tab in Backoffice Administration Cockpit, or allowedPrincipals in the type system). Users who are not specified for this attribute are not allowed to access the category. Hierarchically structured usergroups inherit visibility settings from their parent.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/d8eb7348d8584c80a778f70986b5aaff.html

Hope it helps!